# Guid restrictions in Nhibernate Queryover

Tags: nhibernate, guid, queryover

I have two simplest of Entities, similar to:

```
public class User
{
    int id;
    string name;
    Guid Guid;
    IList<Rentals> Rentals;
}

public class Rentals
{
    int Id { get; protected set; }
    User User { get; set; }
    int DvdId { get; set; }
}
```

(I have all the public virtual properties declared and everything, just not mentioning it here to simplify)

Assuming each `User` will have many `Rentals`, I want to select all `DvdId` of a certain user by his Guid.

I am hitting an exception, this one: `could not resolve property: User.Guid`

This is what I am doing in my repository:

```
DetachedCriteria dc = QueryOver.Of<Rentals>()
    .Where(r => r.User.Guid == userGuid)
    .Select(r => r.DvdId)
    .DetachedCriteria;
```

Where `userGuid` is being passed from the unit test. (and it is the one I know exists)

If I do this instead:

```
DetachedCriteria dc = QueryOver.Of<Rentals>()
    .Where(r => r.User.Id == 1) // Note - replaced guid with id (an int)
    .Select(r => r.DvdId)
    .DetachedCriteria;
```

This works just fine. So I am guessing that something needs to be done for guid comparisions..

My mapping for guid is like this: (under UserMap class)

```
Map(x => x.Guid, "Guid")
    .Not.Nullable();
```

I am using fluently to map the entities.

So.... how do I apply restrictions on guids please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Id of a related entity is treated as `special`. The Foreign Key for a many-to-one always gets hydrated. This is because NHibernate uses lazy loaded so this is perfectly valid:-

```
 .Where(r => r.User.Id == 1)
```

However this is not valid as the related entity needs to be hydrated before Guid is set:-

```
.Where(r => r.User.Guid == userGuid)
```

Therefore you will need to Join `User` with `Rentals` in your query, something along the lines of:-

```
 .QueryOver.Of<Rentals>()
 .JoinQueryOver<User>(x => x.User)
 .Where(x => x.Guid == userGuid)
```

Note: This is untested, so any problems let me know.

Comment: Excellent! Now, not only do I know what I need to do to make it work, but I also know why it was not working! Thanks so much. I'd thumb this up more than once if I could!

Answer (score 0):

You can also compare the entity:

```
var user = session.Load<User>(userGuid);
...
.Where(r => r.User == user)
```